# Does a drake switch forms when knocked unconscious?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, shadowrun

When a drake character is in drake form and is knocked unconscious, does he switch back to his metahuman form, or does he stay in drake form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After flipping back and forth between SR4 (20th anniv.) and the Runner's Companion, I would say that **No, you do not change back**.  The transformation has very specific effects and none of them include a time limit that I saw.  Essentially, the character is in both states at once constantly (thanks to the Dual Nature), existing as one in the physical plane and the other in the astral and they can willingly switch between the two.  Your GM might allow you to reflexively roll to change when you're about to pass out but that's a little fast and loose with the rules.

**The only condition I see a Drake changing to human form is if for any reason their Magic trait is permanently reduced to zero**  If it is only changed temporarily, it stays in whatever form it's in at the time of change.

Comment: *wakes up* Huh? An answer? :D That seems to make sense, thanks!